# jQuery - remove div by class when the screen is smaller than 1350px

Tags: jquery, html, width

I am working on a site with parallax scrolling that consists of 4 'pages' on which you can scroll trough by pressing an up or down button.

The first 'page' contains a video background. There is no need for this 'page' to be visible on tablet and mobile. I can hide this 'page' by using media queries, but this breaks the parallax scrolling functionality as the script of this functionality still sees the hidden div.

So to not show the page, I thought the best way was to fully remove the div. Since this can't be done by Media Queries i'm searching for a way with jQuery to remove the div by class when the screens width is smaller than 1350px

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: you can use bootstrap.js and it's css for doing such things to make the page responsive. if you want.

Comment: Why not just hiding it?

Comment: Take a look at JQuery's [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method.

Comment: When hiding the div, the main functionally of the site doesn't work. As the script of this functionality will still see it in the code even tough it is hidden

Comment: @Brendan Maybe you'd have better to ask question regarding this issue, instead of the fix you think would fix it

Comment: You should anyway clarify what should happen on resize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia):

```
$(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1350px)").matches) {
        $('div.myClass').remove();
    }
});
```

[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)

[Polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)

Comment: I wonder if `onresize` event listener makes sense here.. Because after `div` is removed event is no longer needed anymore. Something unclear with this question.

Comment: I clarified my question above! Sorry for being a bit unclear. This solution does the trick perfectly without breaking the site! Thanks allot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to use media queries, I assume that you are also not interested in dynamic behavior - I mean to show/append div back if window width expands. In this case you can do as simple as this for one time removal:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1350) {
    $('.class-name').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer is currently from the second code example of Jquery documentation (see below) :

```
var screenSizeLimit = 1350;

if( window.screen.width < screenSizeLimit ){
    $( ".yourDivClass" ).remove();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: i don't understand why you'r saying, i didn't provide an answer ... if read clearly the autor post , he is looking for a solution to remove a div from his page. am i wrong ?

Comment: Thats my bad, apologize for the same :) I was thinking why you don't add comment..now I understand you don't have enough reputation to add comment. :) Keep answering..Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>

(function($){
        $(window).load(function(){                
            var win =$(window);

            if(win.width()<1350)
            {             
                $( ".hello" ).remove();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        });

$(window).resize(function(){                
            var win =$(window);

            if(win.width()<1350)
            {             
                $( ".hello" ).remove();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        });
})(jQuery);
```